# Is there a FileVault compatible 3rd party Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, encryption, filevault

Whole disk encryption on macOS requires HID devices to be able to connect before most of the system has booted up. Logitech support recommends turning off FileVault (!!) or not to use Bluetooth (their HIDs come with an alternative dongle so that the OS doesn't have to deal with the wireless collection).

My question is: Does Apple even offer a way for 3rd party manufacturers to build FileVault compatible Bluetooth HIDs? And if so, is there a list of compatible non-Apple devices?

Comment: I'd compatibility will depend on the specific firmware version the Mac has, which in turn may depend on both the hardware model and the latest OS that's been installed on it. Thus, it may not be a simple compatibility list, but a complex multidimensional compatibility matrix (that I doubt anyone has the time or motivation to create).

Answer (score 1):

My [Logitech ERGO K860](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/k860-split-ergonomic.920-009166.html) works fine for FileVault with BlueTooth, even though Logitech setup warns that it might not

Don't think you'll ever find a "list of supported devices" from Apple though - they're pretty tight on just promoting their own HW.

Comment: ERGO K860 doesn't for me unless I use the Bolt receiver they provide :(

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to look for the same thing for several hours and the only conclusion I found is there is not :( I know it's probably not the answer you are looking for and you may be pissed off like me.

Using USB receivers instead of a Bluetooth connection is your best bet if you cannot turn off FileVault.

You can also of course switch to using Apple devices, which don't have this restriction.

Last but not least, if you can afford to reboot your system with `sudo fdsetup authrestart` command from Terminal every time, you would find the Bluetooth devices would work.

Hopefully, it helps. I ended up disabling FileVault.